# Generic types in higher order functions

Tags: typescript

I would like to use a generic type as the parameter in the inner function of a higher order function. However, when I do this, the parameter(s) on the outer function lose their types (become `any`).

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do. I expect to get an error on line 2.

```js
type TestFunc = <T>(outerArg: string) => (innerArg: T) => number
const test: TestFunc = <T>(outerArg) => (innerArg: T) => innerArg ? outerArg * 3 : 0 // no error because `outerArg` is `any` (unexpected)
```

When `innerArg` is not generic, I get the error I expect:

```js
type TestFunc = (outerArg: string) => (innerArg: boolean) => number
const test: TestFunc = (outerArg) => (innerArg: boolean) => innerArg ? outerArg * 3 : 0 // error because `outerArg` is `string` (expected)
```

#### Question

On line 2 in the first example, `outerArg` has type `any`. On line 2 in the second example, `outerArg` has type `string`. Why are they different?

---

#### More details

My goal is to allow `T` to be specified when evaluating the outer function. For example:

```js
type TestFunc = <T>(outerArg: string) => (innerArg: T) => number
const test: TestFunc = (outerArg) => (innerArg) => innerArg ? outerArg.length * 3 : 0 
const test2: TestFunc = <T>(outerArg) => (innerArg: T) => innerArg ? outerArg * 3 : 0 // want error


const fourBool = test<boolean>('str')
console.log(fourBool(true))
console.log(fourBool(1)) // want error

const fourNum = test<number>('str')
console.log(fourNum(true)) // want error
console.log(fourNum(1))
```

Here it is on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20TestFunc%20%3D%20%3CT%3E%28outerArg%3A%20string%29%20%3D%3E%20%28innerArg%3A%20T%29%20%3D%3E%20number%0D%0Aconst%20test%3A%20TestFunc%20%3D%20%28outerArg%29%20%3D%3E%20%28innerArg%29%20%3D%3E%20innerArg%20%3F%20outerArg.length%20%2A%203%20%3A%200%20%0D%0Aconst%20test2%3A%20TestFunc%20%3D%20%3CT%3E%28outerArg%29%20%3D%3E%20%28innerArg%3A%20T%29%20%3D%3E%20innerArg%20%3F%20outerArg%20%2A%203%20%3A%200%20%2F%2F%20want%20error%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fourBool%20%3D%20test%3Cboolean%3E%28%27str%27%29%0D%0Aconsole.log%28fourBool%28true%29%29%0D%0Aconsole.log%28fourBool%281%29%29%20%2F%2F%20want%20error%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fourNum%20%3D%20test%3Cnumber%3E%28%27str%27%29%0D%0Aconsole.log%28fourNum%28true%29%29%20%2F%2F%20want%20error%0D%0Aconsole.log%28fourNum%281%29%29).

Comment: Your outerArg has type string in the top section, and number in the bottom. Might be a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks. I'll edit to make them consistent.

Answer (score 2):

You have two functions:

1) A function with a generic type that returns a number,

2)  and a function that takes a number and returns a generic.

As you mentioned in the comments, you're using an arrow function with a type parameter, but that won't work for both functions. You can declare your inner function as a generic, and your outer function with a type parameter:

```
type InnerFunc<T> = (inner: T) => number;
type TestFunc = <T>(outer: number) => InnerFunc<T>;

const test: TestFunc = <T>(outerArg: number) => (innerArg: T) => innerArg ? outerArg * 3 : 0;

const fourBool = test<boolean>(4);
fourBool(true); // OK
fourBool(1);    // error
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on why `outerArg` implicitly `any` in the first example but not in the second example.

Comment: `noImplicitAny` would certainly give me an error in the first example, but how would I fix that error? Is the only way to say `(outerArg: string)` on line 2 of example 1? That seems redundant, as `outerArg: string` is on the TestFunc type definition.

Comment: I agree that the compiler should say that `outerArg` is a `string` even if you haven't called it yet. This helps when you code so you know ahead of time what it is supposed to be. I still think it is some compiler bug. I don't know if it is by design but that wouldn't make sense to me either.

Comment: Sorry, I actually didn't look very closely at your question. My answer doesn't really answer it, but I don't think that line of thought will address your issue anyway. I believe it's just because your syntax is wrong for what you're trying to do. `type TestFunc<T> = (x: T) => ...` is different than `type TestFunc = <T>(x: T) => ...`. The former is a generic, the latter is a type assertion.

Comment: I can't do `type TestFunc<T> = (outerArg: string) => (innerArg: T) => ...` because I want to specify `T` when I evaluate the outer function. Instead, `TestFunc<T>` forces me to specify `T` when I declare the outer function. I'm having trouble finding any documentation about using type assertions before a function like this. What am I asserting will have type `T`?

Comment: Finally found the documentation: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#411-arrow-functions . The bottom of 4.11 says that this is not a type assertion but rather "an arrow function with a type parameter"

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this might be a bug in the compiler or by design.

But this might work as a work around for now where you attach the generic type to the function that uses the generic type.

```
type TestFunc = (outerArg: string) => <T>(innerArg: T) => number
```

OK, this is the way you would want to approach it to do what you want:

```
type TestFunc = (arg1: string) => <T>(a: T) => number
type Number1 = (a: number) => number
const test: TestFunc = (arg1) => (a) => a ? (arg1 ? 1 : 2) : 0
const num1: Number1 = test("blah")
// OR
const newNum1 = <Number1>test("bleh")
```

Above will give you the error if you place `arg1` like you did before and it will get you the generic form you wanted before. You will notice if you define the "sub type" incorrectly it will also give a compilation error.

For completeness here is a simpler solution (pretty much what cdbajorin did in his solution):

```
type TestFunc1 = <T>(arg1: string) => (a: T) => number
const test1: TestFunc1 = (arg1: string) => a => a ? (arg1 ? 1 : 2) : 0
const newNum2 = test1<number>("bluh")
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon49. This approach seems to be on the right track, as it does give an error on line 2 of my example. However, I don't see how I can specify `T` when I evaluate the outer function. I'll update the original question with an example.

Comment: Specifically, your suggestion correctly gives an error on line 3 of the code block in "More details" but gives unwanted errors on the lines like this: `const fourBool = test<boolean>(4)`

Comment: Thanks Jon. In this approach, it looks like I will have to create a separate type for each inner function? For example, if I wanted the inner function's argument to be a boolean, I'd have to do this: `type BoolFunc = (innarArg: boolean) => number`? I see how that would work, but it seems verbose. Isn't the point of using generics to avoid that verbosity?

Comment: Ideally but, it appears there is a bug in TypeScript, like I said before, so you aren't going to get the ideal solution. Basically, if you want something simple you'll have to do what cdbajorin did in his solution. Where you define Arg1 twice.